# Array of PdfPTables[] nullpointer exception when filling

Tags: java, arrays, pdfptable

I'm trying  to create an Array of tables (2 tables). 
My program stops on the last line with a nullpointer exception. Any idea why?

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable[] table = new com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable[1];
// the cell object
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell;
// header

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(wdComponentAPI.getMessage("Ordernr")));
cell.setColspan(1);
cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table[0].addCell(cell);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays dont come created with objects created

```
PdfPTable [] tables = new PdfPTable[1];
tables[0].doStuff() // null pointer
```

create the objects inside the array

```
PdfPTable [] tables = new PdfPTable[1];
tables[0] = new PdfPTable();
tables[0].doStuff() // works good!
```

Answer (score 1):

You created and array, but there is nothing in it. Array field "table[0]" contains null.

Add there object like this:

```
tables[0] = new PdfPTable();
```

Or use a different contructor than PdfPTable(), according to what you exactly need

Here is your code updated

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable[] table = new com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable[1];
tables[0] = new PdfPTable();
// the cell object
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell cell;
// header

cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(wdComponentAPI.getMessage("Ordernr")));
cell.setColspan(1);
cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table[0].addCell(cell);
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable[] table = new com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable[1];
```

You just create an array of the length 1, `table[0]` is still `null` at this point. You have to create an object and assign it to it before you can use it

```
table[0] = new PdfPTable(1); // create a PDFTable with one column
```